# Maven Integration Test Speed

Tags: maven, groovy, automated-tests

My maven invoker integration tests were fast (1-3 sec), but after adding a validate groovy script they slow down to a minimum of 20 sec each.

Have someone a idea, how to speed up the groovy execution of maven invoker plugin?

Comment: Have you taken a look into the output of invoker I made the experience that the maven takes the time not the groovy part.